# How to get value in function?

Tags: javascript

I want to get return value to some function.

script

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    var latitude = positon.coords.latitude;   // I want to return this
});

var mapContainer = document.getElementById('map'),
    mapOption = { 
        center : new daum.maps.LatLng(***I need latitude here***),
        level : 3
    };

var map = new daum.maps.Map(mapContainer, mpOption);
```

/script

Actually, this is my code, but I don't want this. I want only returned value.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    var mapContainer = document.getElementById('map'), 
        mapOption = {
            center : new daum.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                      position.coords.longitude), 
            level : 3
        };

    var map = new daum.maps.Map(mapContainer, mapOption);
});
```

[image]

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzhoX.jpg)

Comment: Your question does not have enough detail to be able to provide a good answer.  Please supply a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

I have copy pasted your example and tried executing it. There are few basic mistakes. First please close your braces correctly.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    var latitude = positon.coords.latitude;   // I want to return this
});
```

You had written `)}` instead of `})`.

Then the main problem is spelling mistake for **position** in `var latitude = positon.coords.latitude;` line. You should write whatever you have passed in the function and you have passed `position`.

Correct these two problem, your code will work.

Sample code snippet with alert.

```
var latitude;
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        latitude = position.coords.latitude;   // I want to return this
        alert("Current latitude is : " + latitude);
    });
```

Run this code in the console and you should get an alert with the latitude value.

Below is your code snippet. See if this works for you. I ahve just declared the `position` variable outside the function scope so that you can access/ use it later.

```
var latitude = 0; // Initial value of latitude variable
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    latitude = position.coords.latitude;   // Here you are setting the exact value of latitude
});

var mapContainer = document.getElementById('map'),
    mapOption = { 
        center : new daum.maps.LatLng(latitude),
        level : 3
    };

var map = new daum.maps.Map(mapContainer, mapOption);
```

Comment: Sorry it's is my mistake. Because I can't copy&paste my source, so I written my source.

Comment: I know this code, but if alert is out of block, latitude is undefined.

Comment: No problem. But did you try after correcting the spelling of position and braces correction! Is it working now?

Comment: Yes, because scope of latitude variable ends there. So, you need to declare the variable position outside that scope. e.g.  
`var latitude;
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    latitude = position.coords.latitude;   // I want to return this
    alert("Current latitude is : " + latitude);
});`

Comment: Sure, I'm using eclipse. So spell is correct. I mistake only here(stackoverflow).

Comment: Did it work after declaring the `position` variable outside the function scope? `position` will not be undefined in this case. Or you can refer my updated answer where I have done correction in your initial code. Check if that works for you!